# Firebase Auth TypeError: module is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to set up Firebase Auth pre built UI with react
i copied the code from github
i get this error:

***TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.auth is undefined***

[Screenshot of my Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7eXZ.png)

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react

im using VScode and node.js to install packages

```
import React from 'react';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import firebase from 'firebase';

    uiConfig = {
        // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.
        signInOptions: [
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        callbacks: {
          // Avoid redirects after sign-in.
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => false
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 3):

Try importing both firebase, and the specific packages you want to use. I was having the same problem in my app with the "auth" package, but adding it specifically after the generic import, made things work:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
```

You can check it in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Comment: Yes, i have tried but the problem remains the same. For some reason it says auth is undefined

Comment: Thanks. This answer also works for firebaseui. `import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'`